# compare the data in CSV files using mapreduce program

Tags: csv, hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming

I am trying to compare columns of two csv files using mapreduce program

The input csv data files(input for map program)that contains some automated generated data which has around 100 columns and thousands of rows looks in the below format...

Note: CSV file columns are separated by ";"

*Input File1 Data*
**Column1**;**Column2**;**Column3**;**Column4**;-----------
Sigma48_12mar09.9010.9010.3;K.TAFQEALDAAGDKLVVVDFSATWC[160.14]GPC[160.14]K.M;P08263.3;1.062
Sigma48_12mar09.9063.9063.3;K.KDPEGLFLQDNIVAEFSVDETGQMSATAK.G;P08263.3;1.062

*Input File2 Data*
**Column1**;**Column2**;**Column3**;**Column4**;----------- 
Sigma48_12mar09.9188.9188.2;R.YKLSLEFPSGYPYNAPTVK.F;P08263.3;1.062
Sigma48_12mar09.9314.9314.2;R.YKLSLEFPSGYPYNAPTVK.FP08263.3;1.062
Sigma48_12mar09.9010.9010.3;K.TAFQEALDAAGDKLVVVDFSATWC[160.14]GPC[160.14]K.M;P08263.3;1.062

My requirement :

Read all the rows in **Input File1 Data.csv** take *column1* and read all rows in **Input File2 Data.csv**, then compare the column1 in first file with column1 in the second file.

When match found compare all other columns in the above two files for that particular **row** and write the matched data in to the HDFS and should return the % matched among those two input files.

Mycode is as follows..

```
/* First Mapper */
public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) 
            throws IOException, InterruptedException{

        String line = value.toString();
        String[] words = line.split(";");
        String name = words[1];
        String other = words[2];
        context.write(new Text(name), new Text(line));

    }
}

  /* Second Mapper */

public static class InputMapper2 extends Mapper<LongWritable,Text,Text,Text>{

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context)
              throws IOException, InterruptedException
              {
        String line = value.toString();

        String[] words = line.split(";");
        String name = words[1];
        String other = words[2];
        System.out.println(key);
        context.write(new Text(name), new Text(line));


              }

              }

  /* Reducer for both of the mappers */
  /*incomplete and have to compare the two csv files here */

public static class CounterReducer extends Reducer
 {
  String line=null;

  public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context ) 
  throws IOException, InterruptedException
  {

    Iterator<Text> val = values.iterator();



   for(Text value:values)
   {
    line = value.toString();
   }

   context.write(key, new Text(line));
 }
}
```

Comment: You can use Multipleinputformat and define 2 mappers, one for each input source and then output same key in both mappers then you can do your comparison for contents of same key in reducer. If can you give more details about fields and take an example to demonstrate what you are trying to achieve then more detailed answer can be provided.

Comment: do i need to iterate the keys among themselves to compare?

Comment: It's technically impossible under the Map Reduce programming model as the ordering of the input does not exist - it's an operation on multisets.  You need a common key to join by.  The only way would be by treating each file as an entire record - then that will require splitting your data up into perfectly matching file line counts, again not easy as you split by data size not line counts.

Comment: Can i take the first column as the common key? in both of the files and compare those keys for matching?

Comment: May be Joins can be used here to compare two files
more information in the below link
http://kickstarthadoop.blogspot.co.il/2011/09/joins-with-plain-map-reduce.html